# Multi domain from a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to create multi-domain for one lambda function?

For example api.domain1.com, api.domain2.org, api.domain3.net

All of those API, using only one lambda function. Is it possible? Is there any documentation about it?

Best Regards

Comment: You are thinking of using a single Lambda function into multiple APIs, right ?

Comment: Yes correct, single lambda function, but with multi domain or API.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda charges are based on the number of invocations of your function and the time it takes for your function to run. Whenever your lambda function is called, it will be charged for the invocation and its duration.

**So yes, it is possible to connect your Lambda to multiple APIs in API gateway and use them.**

Different endpoints of any API gateway can point to same lambda.